# How do navigate to desired url after successful login?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUserInfo } from '../../features/auth/authSlice';

const RequireAuth = () => {
  const user = useSelector(selectUserInfo);
  const location = useLocation();

  return user?.accessToken ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/sign-in" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  );
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

The RequireAuth component works fine as it gets redirected to '/sign-in' is the route is protected.

**SignIn.jsx**

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';

import Input from '../components/inputs/Input';
import Button from '../components/ui/Button';

import { login } from '../features/auth/authSlice';

const SignIn = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);
  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/';

  const formSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().min(1, 'Enter your email').email('Invalid email'),
    password: z.string().min(1, 'Enter your password'),
  });

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      await dispatch(login(values));
      console.log(from);
      navigate(from, { replace: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen container">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <div className="w-1/2 h-full flex flex-col gap-4">
          <Input
            id="email"
            label="Email"
            type="text"
            disabled={isSubmitting}
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
          />
          <Input
            id="password"
            label="Password"
            type="text"
            disabled={isSubmitting}
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
          />
          <Button label="Sign In" onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} size="md" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

On console logging the from, the desired output is achieved. Though after successful login, the page is not navigated to the desired location. The navigation only works when the value of from is '/'.

**App.jsx**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<UserLayout />}>
          <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path="/:name/:productId" element={<ProductDetails />} />

          <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
            <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code. Is there anything navigating a user back to the login page after successful authentication? Are there any other details or debugging information you can provide?

Comment: Thanks you @DrewReese. I found an error in the RequireAuth Component where the userInfo was not being received. On correcting it, the problem was solved.